# debug a wav file to play different sounds on the left headphone & right headphone

Tags: matlab, audio

I'm trying to define a wav file to play a sound on the left headphone which is different than the sound played on the right headphone,
I'm trying to use matlab but get nothing it still play the same sound on both left & right

```
clc;clear;close all;
t=0:0.1*10^-3:20;
length(t)
fs=80000;
waveFile='test8.wav';
x=ones(1,8);
z=zeros(1,8);
v=[x z];
y=repmat([x z x x x],1,60000);
b=sin (2*pi*3000*t);
audiowrite(waveFile,[zeros(1,length(y)) , y],fs);
% player=audioplayer([y,zeros(1,length(y))],fs);
% player.play();
```

Comment: As a bit of a guess, try `[zeros(length(y),1) y.']`, since I think the signal should be m rows by 2 columns.

Comment: I changed them into two columns instead of rows and it works okay.
thanks for helping me :)